# Running Node Red vs Azure IoT edge modules in an edge device

Tags: azure, iot, node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I`m comparing running Node Red on an edge device vs running Azure IoT edge modules in an edge device. As per your experience; when compared what are the advantages of disadvantages both.

Comment: This type of question is off topic for Stack Overflow, this is not a place for a discussion, or opinion based answers. It is also far too broad, one is a programming environment that can do any number of tasks

Comment: I agree with @hardillb. You can try your luck at [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/topics/single/25493.html?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). In either case, include the use case you're trying to build.

Comment: as far as I understood running Node-RED on IoT edge device enables you to store some data for a certain period on the edge device when the connection is down

Answer (score 1):

Node-Red nodes for Azure IoT Edge :

1. This package contains the Node-RED nodes that can be deployed to a Node-RED container running as an Azure IoT Edge module.
2. These nodes enable you to interact with the IoT Edge platform using Node-RED.
3. They will only work if the nodes are installed on a IoT Edge module running Node-RED.
4. The nodes are also available as a procreated module for Azure IoT Edge.

Reference Link: https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule

Comment: I have already gone through this but thank you for sharing